# Tracing DataTables and DataSets

Tags: .net, dataset, trace

is there any way in debugging I look at my dataset tables and their members and kinda trace the dataset as well? The same with datatables... Thanks!

Comment: you can add them in `Watch` and `Quick Watch`

Comment: Maybe a DebugerVisualizer comes in handy... http://cs.rthand.com/files/folders/righthand_downloads/tags/.net/Visualizer/default.aspx

Comment: @ Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy : I'm sorry but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Immediate Window that appears at the bottom of VS.
Also check this link [Creating Debugger Visualizers](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/27821/1954).
it will also work on VS 2008 and 2010.